# How to do a simple loop for insert in Amazon Redshift?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift, plpgsql

I would like to do a very simple pl/sql transaction with loop and for to insert values into a table. It should work like this:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE cs_refresh_reports() AS $$
DECLARE
  last_nps RECORD;
BEGIN

  FOR last_nps IN SELECT "date" FROM table_1 ;
  LOOP
  EXECUTE insert into table_2 ("value") select "value" from table_3 where "date" = :last_nps ;
  END LOOP;
RETURN;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Very simple but I didn't find any solution for this and if I try I just get errors.

Comment: Why don't you join the tables table_1 and table_3 and insert the result into your target table?

Comment: Because I want to have the duplicates in the new table. 

ID1 Value1        
ID1 Value2
ID1 Value3
ID2 Value1
ID2 Value3
ID3 Value1
etc. 

Individual select for all ID's

Comment: And with union would be way too long

Comment: You can do this but it will be SLOW.  Databases are just not optimized to do this.  I expect you will be better off with a LAG() window function but exactly what you are trying to do isn't clear. If you post some sample source data and expected results I'd be happy to help.  If you really insist on a looping stored procedure, you're like not going to like it, I can help with that also.

Comment: Do NOT do single-row inserts in Amazon Redshift. It is optimized for bulk loading and INSERT should only be used with multiple rows. Please show us some sample input rows and some sample rows of the result you would like to achieve.